# Is HTTP Status Codes Example Of REST?

Tags: rest, http, web-applications, penetration-testing

I am new to web-app and was learning about REST , and in the definition it said

**"... in which requests and responses contain representations of the current state of the system's resources .."**

And in a Way HTTP Status Code are a representation of current state of system's resource ?
I mean , 200 means Everything's Fine and 404 means not found , So In way they are representation of current state of system's resource ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is HTTP Status Codes Example Of REST?

No.

But status codes are an example of *one part* of REST; specifically the idea that the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) includes "self-descriptive messages".

> So In way they are representation of current state of system's resource ?

No.  The [representation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2) is the thing that appears in the message body.  Depending on the context, that representation can be a representation of a resource, or a representation of a status of an action, or a representation of an explanation of an error situation....

The status codes are metadata that [describe the response](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)

> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request.  The rest of the response message is to be interpreted in light of the semantics defined for that status code.